# How to implement the following algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am sorry for the enigmatic title. Here is my problem:

```
class Item
{
public:
    double value;
    void recomputeValue();   // after this, will probably increase a little, 
                             // but never decrease.
    std::list<Item*> neighbors;  // relatively few items
};
```

I am trying to implement a procedure, which would trim a list of these items to a specified size:

```
void trimToNewSize(std::list<Item*>& items, int newSize);
```

The algorithm that needs to be implemented is:

```
while (size > newSize)
{
   erase item with smallest value;
   recomputeValue() for all its neighbors;
}
```

I have sofar considered 2 approaches:

**1. The heap**

Construct a heap from all the values. Heap is apropriate, because it can find and remove the minimal element in O(1) and can be constructed in O(n).

After each removal, locate all the neighbors in the heap, `recomputeValue()` and update their position in the heap.

So I have done some shallow study of the Heap datastructure on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html)
The *problem* is that it seems that the Heap does not provide a fast way to **locate** elements in it.

**2. The hashtable**

Sort the list by the value. Construct a hash table mapping the pointers Item* to iterators pointing to them in the linked list. Then each time I remove the top (minimal) item from the list, I find all its neighbors in the list in constant time thanks to the hashtable. Then for each neighbor `recomputeValue()` and update its position in the list and the corresponding iterator in the hashtable.

Maybe the need for a hashtable would be eliminated if I used an ordered skiplist instead of a linked list.

I am new to programming, so my approaches are probably too naive and complicated and I welcome any advice.

To summarize my question:

1. Is there a way to perform fast lookups in a heap to make #1 feasible?
2. Is there a container that maintains order of elements and can perform quick lookups, so     that I can make #2 cleaner?
3. How would You handle the problem?

Comment: as for the heap, after total-recomputation I think that 'constructing new heap' would be faster than 'updating old heap'. But that's just a hunch

Comment: I forgot to mention, that each item has only a small number of neighbors, so only a few recomputations would occur.

Comment: It is very positive thing that you are doing thorough research. However, have you investigated the null hypothesis that "it does not matter"? How many items/neighbours will you have? You now added that "few neighbours'. For FEW, there's for example no real difference in O(N) or O(NlgN), etc, and even the constant factor that's missing from O() notation may be more important than the O() factor itself!

Comment: You could use a [boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for a plain old `std::map< double, Item * >`. It gives you the minimum element as `* items.begin()`, and to recompute a neighbor, just do something like

```
typedef std::map< double, Item * > itemsByValue;
itemsByValue items;

class Item
{
public:
    double value;
    void recomputeValue();   // after this, will probably increase a little, 
                             // but never decrease.
    std::list< itemContainer::iterator > neighbors;  // relatively few items
};

for ( itemsByValue::iterator i = neighbors.begin();
      i != neighbors.end(); ++ i ) {
    Item &item = * neighbor;
    items.erase( neighbor );
    item.recomputeValue();
    items.insert( std::make_pair( item.value, & item ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So I should use the hashtable alternative?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Huh? Where did I mention a hashtable? Unfortunately `std::unordered_multimap` doesn't provide the `lower_bound` operation which you need to find an insertion point, so the tree is necessary.

Comment: I was refering to #2 in my question. I am using QHashTable, but I think, this is just an equivalent to std::unordered_multimap. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Eh, now you've accepted but I need to change the answer. There "cache" which I suggested is actually doing all the work and there's no need for a `list` at all.

Comment: But if you use an std::unordered_multimap it can speedup significantly, since searching in the cache would not be O(ln n), but O(1)

Comment: @MartinDrozdik see my update. You won't get away from the logarithmic complexity. The unordered map won't work because you need the ordering. The items are sorted and you want to find the position following a given value, not the element at a precise given value regardless of order.